# Vert.x with Rx-Java implementing caching for a service call

Tags: java, caching, rx-java, vert.x

Say, `SomeOtherService` in one `Veritcle` use UserService in different Verticle, the communication happens over the Event Bus.
To represent it:

```
class SomeOtherService {

    final UserService userService = new UserService();

    // Mutable state
    final Map<String, Single<String>> cache = new HashMap(); // Not Synchronized ?

    public Single<String> getUserSessionInfo(String id) {
        // Seems it is not save ! :
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(id, _id -> {
                log("could not find " + id + " in cache. Connecting to userService...");
                return userService.getUserSessionInfo(id); // uses generated proxy to send msg to the event bus to call it
            }
        );
    }
}
```

// Somewhere in another verticle/micro-service on another machine.

```
class UserService {

    public Single<String> getUserSessionInfo(String id) {
        return Single.fromCallable( () -> {

            waitForOneSecond();

            log("getUserSessionInfo for " + id);

            if (id.equals("1"))
                return "one";
            if (id.equals("2"))
                return "two";

            else throw new Exception("could not"); // is it legal?

           }
        );
    }
```

And the client code, where we subscribe and deciding about the scheduler:

```
 final Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.from(new String[] {"1", "1"});


        // Emulating sequential call of 'getUserSessionInfo' to fork in separate scheduler A
        obs.flatMap(id -> {
                    log("flatMap"); // on main thread
                    return someOtherService.getUserSessionInfo(id)
                                           .subscribeOn(schedulerA) // Forking. will thread starvation happen? (since we have only 10 threads in the pool)
                                           .toObservable(); 
                }
        ).subscribe(
                x -> log("next: " + x)
        );
```

The question is, how good is the solution to use `HashMap` for the cache (since it is the shared state here) by using the computeIfAbsent method?

Even though we are using Event Loop & Event Bus it would not save us from shared state and possible concurrency issue, assuming that log-operation (like `getUserSessionInfo(id)` happens in separate scheduler/threads?

Should I use `ReplySubject` instead to implement caching? What is the best practices for vert.x + rx-java?

Seems that as loon as `cache.computeIfAbsent` is run on EventLoop it is safe because it is sequential ?

Sorry.. a lot of questions, I guess I can narrow down to: What is the best practices to implement Cash for the Service calls in Vert.x and Rx-Java?

The whole example is [here](https://github.com/Sergey80/rx-java-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/samples/SimpleSample5.java):

Comment: I think I found my answer here: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/ - Observable<Data> source = Observable  
  .concat(memory, diskWithCache, networkWithSave)
  .first(); and when I save it by using map.put(..) explicitly instead of using computeIfAbsent

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer here: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/ -

```
Observable<Data> source = Observable .concat(memory, diskWithCache, networkWithSave) .first();
```

and when I save it by using map.put(..) explicitly instead of using computeIfAbsent

and as log I'm on the event-loop I'm safe to use un-sychronized cash map